# Nuclear density and nuclear force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics

The density of the nucleus is independent of A (the mass number) what does this tell us about the nuclear force ?

Comment: This question may be inelegantly stated, but the phenomenon described is known as the saturation of nuclear forces (SNF).  SNF is responsible for the existence of neutron stars.  There is still no fundamental answer to the question of what causes SNF (it is probably related to QCD color confinement).  There is however an explanation (a somewhat subtle one) on the basis of the effective interactions associated with relativistic mean field theory.  These effective interactions are associated with meson exchange models of nucleon-nucleon interactions.  Perhaps an edit could improve the question.